# Summing the probability distribution to 1 to convince myself

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, distributions, summation

I have worked out a probability distribution and want to check its sum which is necessarily 1.

First we write
$$
  r \triangleq \frac{(2 \lambda + \mu)^2}{2(\mu + \lambda)^2}, \quad s \triangleq \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mu}{\mu + \lambda}, \quad \textrm{ and } p_0 = \frac{1}{2} \big( 1 + (\frac{\lambda}{\mu + \lambda})^2 \big)
$$

where, $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$.

The sum I want to evaluate is

$$
p_0^{n} + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n \choose k} {m-1 \choose n-k-1} p_0^{k} r^{n-k} s^{m}
$$

where, $m, n \in \mathbb{N}^{+} \text{ and } k \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

*Questions:*

> - How to evaluate this sum of probability distribution involving double sum and binomials (to 1 *as I wish*)?
> - If it is not feasible for *Mathematica* to work on general parameter $n$, how should I convince myself of the results for larger values (i.e., $n \geq 7$ explained below)?

---

*My code:*

```
r = (2 λ + μ)^2 / (2 (μ + λ)^2);
s  = (1/2 (μ/(μ + λ)));
pzero = (1/2) (1 + (λ/(μ + λ))^2);

pnm = Sum[Binomial[n, k] Binomial[m - 1, n - k - 1] (pzero^k) (r^(n - k)) (s^m), 
  {k, 0, n - 1}, 
  Assumptions -> λ > 0 && μ > 0 && m > 0 && n > 0 && k >= 0
     && λ ∈ Integers && μ ∈ Integers 
     && m ∈ Integers && n ∈ Integers && k ∈ Integers] 
  // FullSimplify;

pn = Sum[pnm, {m, 1, Infinity}] + pzero^n // FullSimplify
```

---

*Partial results:*

For $n = 1,2,3,4,5,6$, it is indeed 1.

```
Table[pn, {n, 1, 6}] // FullSimplify

*{1,1,1,1,1,1}*
```

However, for larger $n$ values, it produces complex results:

```
Table[pn, {n, 7, 10}] // FullSimplify // Short
```

$$\left\{\frac{1}{128}\left(1+\frac{\lambda ^2}{\langle\langle 1\rangle\rangle ^2}\right)^7+\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \frac{2^{-m-7}\langle\langle 4\rangle\rangle \text{Binomial}[\langle\langle 1\rangle\rangle ]}{(m-6)\langle\langle 4\rangle\rangle (m-1)},\langle\langle 3\rangle\rangle \right\}$$

**EDIT (11-24-2014)**

Using `FunctionExpand` as mentioned in comments, `Table[pn, {n, 7, 10}] // FullSimplify` gives $1$. For general $n$, it produces

[image: function-expand]

Comment: You can wrap `FunctionExpand` around your definition of `pnm`. That will replace `Binomamial` with `Gamma` functions and remove the apparent zeros in the denominator.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thanks. `FunctionExpand` works. I have tried `Table[pn, {n,7,10}]`. Larger values (11 $\sim$ 20) are under test (taking much time). Then I will try general $n$. Would you mind converting the comment to an answer?

Comment: @b.gatessucks And it would be much nicer to give some explanation why (and how) `FunctionExpand` works.